# Getting random but frequent err_ssl_version_interference, err_ssl_protocol_version

Tags: ssl-certificate, windows-server-2016, ssl-certificate-errors

I have a asp.net core api hosted in a service fabric cluster on windows server. We configured the https following this [guide](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-tutorial-dotnet-app-enable-https-endpoint).

We are getting a lot of err_ssl_version_interference, err_ssl_protocol_version in chrome and I'm seeing a lot of events with TLS 1.0, TLS 1.1 and TLS 1.2

> An TLS 1.1 connection request was received from a remote client
> application, but none of the cipher suites supported by the client
> application are supported by the server. The TLS connection request
> has failed.

and also the events

> SSL Certificate Settings deleted for endpoint : 0.0.0.0:20000 .
>
> SSL Certificate Settings created by an admin process for endpoint :
> 0.0.0.0:20000 .

I'm hosting several other web apps with the same wildcard certificate and I don't know how to troubleshoot this errors.

Comment: check if this link is helpful to you https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/2025598/https-connections-fail-and-ssl-bindings-are-deleted-for-a-website-in-i

Comment: there is no iis in our deployment. Web api are hosted using kestrel and there is a load balancer in front of our machines.

Comment: Since I was not aware of your environment what I meant was **The SSL binding for the website has been deleted and not replaced, or has been deleted and replaced with invalid certificate info.  The problem occurs because of a legacy SSL certificate hash property interfering with the current SSL binding, resulting in the correct binding being deleted.**